# How can I check HyperLink response for custom chatbot using botium-connector-webdriverio

Tags: automation, chatbot, webdriver-io

My bot response contains text and hyperlink in single message. I am using botium-connector-webdriverio to verify bot responses in my website. In this connector capability , it is define that I can use BUTTONS to verify link, But I am unable to verify it. Could you please help.
[please find bot element in website here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndIW8.png)

botium.json,

defined below capability for hyperlink
"WEBDRIVERIO_OUTPUT_ELEMENT_BUTTONS":"//div[contains(@class,'msg-left')]/a",

in convo file, I have defined below expected response

#bot
 BUTTONS https://***/mobile-app-development/chatbot-platform

Getting below error
 Error: hello/Line 12: assertion error - Error: Line 12: Expected buttons with text "https://---/mobile-app-development/chatbot-platform"
    at ButtonsAsserter.assertConvoStep (F:\Bot_Training_Automation\Website\node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\logichook\asserter\ButtonsAsserter.js:19:61)
    at p (F:\Bot_Training_Automation\Website\node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\ScriptingProvider.js:111:61)
    at Promise (F:\Bot_Training_Automation\Website\node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\ScriptingProvider.js:17:13)
    at new Promise ()
    at p (F:\Bot_Training_Automation\Website\node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\ScriptingProvider.js:15:19)
    at asserters.filter.map.a (F:\Bot_Training_Automation\Website\node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\ScriptingProvider.js:111:17)
    at Array.map ()
    at ScriptingProvider._createAsserterPromises (F:\Bot_Training_Automation\Website\node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\ScriptingProvider.js:111:8)
    at ScriptingProvider.assertConvoStep (F:\Bot_Training_Automation\Website\node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\ScriptingProvider.js:61:21)
    at scriptingEvents.onBotStart.then.then (F:\Bot_Training_Automation\Website\node_modules\botium-core\src\scripting\Convo.js:345:36)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Comment: Please attach verbose output. As far as I can tell, the button will appear as "Know More" to Botium.

Comment: Yes, it is displaying "know more" in response and and also in botium. I have written text and hyperlink in text response of watson dialog. Is there any way to check for hyperlinks in text response? I am using botium-bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Botium can check for the existance of hyperlinks in the text response. In your case, I assume you want to verify the Hyperlink behind the Button.

- The first thing to do is to tell Botium the Selenium selector for a Button. This is done with the [WEBDRIVERIO_OUTPUT_ELEMENT_BUTTONS](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-webdriverio#webdriverio_output_element_buttons) capability - you already did that.
- Second, you have to tell Botium what other Media are attached by using the [WEBDRIVERIO_OUTPUT_ELEMENT_MEDIA](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-webdriverio#webdriverio_output_element_media) capability.
- For Buttons, Botium will select the **Text** only, not the hyperlink (if it has a hyperlink at all). This is something I just added to our Botium backlog, as I consider this a missing feature.
- You can then use the [BUTTONS](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/17399914/Buttons+Asserter) and [MEDIA](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/17465355/Media+Asserter) asserters for verifying the existance of buttons and media files in the chatbot response.

For verifying the existance of a hyperlink in the chatbot response, there is the [Hyperlink Existance Asserter](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-asserter-basiclink) - it is preconfigured in Botium Box, but you can use it with Botium Bindings and Botium CLI as well.

The [Botium Platform](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/360471/Botium+Platform) additionaly delivers a [Hyperlink Response Asserter](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/2359360/Hyperlink+Response+Asserter+Enterprise).

Comment: Can I use Hyperlink Response Asserter with botium bindings?

Comment: Could you please provide the depandancy package for hyperlink response asserter. It is not available on https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki and also How can I set up with botium bindings?

Comment: the hyperlink reponse asserter is part of botium platform, which is a paid product. the hyperlink existance asserter is on github and npmjs (npm install botium-asserter-basiclink)